# Сортировка списка по части елемента нижеописанным алгоритмом

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть список out = ['123 700', '456 -300', '789 -200'] состоящий из 3 элементов разделенных точкой с запятой. Каждый элемент - это номер счета - пробел - сумма.
Нужно отсортировать список по сумме таким алгоритмом:
Проходим циклом по всем элементам и сохраняем в переменную вне цикла элемент с минимальной суммой.
После выполнения цикла записываем эту сумму в новый список outsort и удаляем ее из out. У меня все работает правильно, но строка с удалением ломает алгоритм, как изменить код, чтоб удалять правильно?

```
out = ['123 700', '456 -300', '789 -200']
q = 1
minn = "999 99999999"
i_minn = 0
outsort = []
while q <= len(out):
    for i in range(len(out)):
        if int(minn[4:]) > int(out[i][4:]):
            minn = out[i]
            i_minn = i
    outsort.append(minn)
    del out[i_minn]
    q += 1

print(out)
print(outsort)

['123 700', '456 -300', '789 -200'] - исходный список
['456 -300', '789 -200', '123 700'] - ожидаемый список
['456 -300', '456 -300'] - то что получается этим кодом
```

Comment: Что такое 789 -300 - строка? Для кода в вопросе это даёт SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Сергей, 789 -300  - это элемент списка. В конце каждого элемента стоит точка с запятой.
Каждый элемент это: номер счета в банке (789) - пробел - сумма на счету (-300)

Comment: У меня такой список сразу выдавал ошибку. Вижу,что теперь код исправлен.

Comment: Это строка, верно, теперь обернул кавычками, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так надо, если алгоритм не менять (и фраза "строка с удалением ломает алгоритм" сбивает с толку - с этой строкой всё нормально):

```
out = ['123 700', '456 -300', '789 -200']
# Тут не нужен i_minn
outsort = []
# Поменяли неверное условие выхода и убрали лишний счетчик
while len(out):
    # Поменяли минимальный элемент  
    minn = '999 999999999'
    for i in range(len(out)):
        if int(minn[4:]) >= int(out[i][4:]):
            minn = out[i]
            i_minn = i
    outsort.append(minn)
    del out[i_minn]

print(out)
print(outsort)
```

Если поменять алгоритм:

```
out = ['123 700', '456 -300', '789 -200']
outsort = sorted(out, key=lambda x: int(x[4:]))
print (outsort)
```

Comment: Спасибо за иные способы. Я разобрался как сортировать с помощью sort, lambda.
Но в алгоритме описанном в условии ошибка и на форум я пишу т.к. хочу ее найти, нужно отсортировать таким алгоритмом. А плохой он или нет в моей задаче не важно.

Сейчас пришел к выводу, что после каждого цикла из исходного списка out удаляется нужный элемент с минимальной суммой, тут все правльно. Но в outsort записывается один и тот же элемент, с первой найденной минимальной суммой, проблема в этом...

Comment: Я потому и оставил вам ваш алгоритм. Просто исправил ошибки его реализации и избыточность убрал - смотрите комментарии в коде. Если нравится, то нажимайте на треугольник вверх, если решает проблему - принимайте (галочка под треугольником).

Comment: Ваш код дает такой результат:
['789 -200', '456 -300', '123 700']
 Из-за того, что     # Поменяли минимальный элемент.
Делает почти тоже самое что и мой код) Надо найти ошибку)

Comment: Проверяйте - исправил, это я дооптимизировался:-) int зря убрал.

Comment: Теперь все работает, когда minn объявляется в цикле while) Отлично! Остальные оптимизации тоже ясны, спасибо.
Но еще одна ошибка, вы присваиваете minn первый элемент списка, если в нем сумма минимальная, то программа не работает. В minn должна быть или бесконечность или число равное сумме на всех счетах или просто не минимальная сумма)

Comment: Я работаю по ТЗ:-) Какой тестовый пример, такое и решение. Написали бы, что нужен широкий спектр проверок - проверил бы. Но хорошо, что заметили. Исправил в ответе.

Comment: Ну в задании последнее предложение это уже описание проблемы, что в коде ошибка, это не ТЗ.
Но ошибка оказалась в другом, так не понять задание легко. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не за что, было интересно. Можете поставить галку, если теперь всё хорошо:-)

Comment: А, так тут еще галка есть, теперь поставил)

Comment: Я все-таки еще раз ошибся в причине ошибки. Алгоритм перезаписи minn то  был правильный, но она всегда была минимальным значением, которое после  for удалялось из out. Поэтому следующее минимальное просто не находилось... Если minn присваивать элемент списка и если на каком-то счету сумма будет меньше - то это та же самая причина)

Answer (score 2):

```
out = ['123 700', '456 -300', '789 -200']
dictionary = {int(x): int(y) for x, y in [(x.split(' ')[0], x.split(' ')[1]) for x in out]}
sorted_dict = sorted(dictionary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
sorted_dict = [' '.join(x) for x in [(str(x), str(y)) for x, y in sorted_dict]]
print(sorted_dict)
```

Вывод, как вы и хотели - `['456 -300', '789 -200', '123 700']`. В строке объявления `dictionary` генерируем словарь по "вторым объектам" строки с помощью генератора словаря и вложенного в него генератора списков. В следующей строке сортируем этот список. Затем склеиваем с помощью `' '.join(x)` и принтим список, который вам нужен.

Comment: Только алгоритм изменён, как понимаю. А в ТЗ: "Нужно отсортировать список по сумме таким алгоритмом".

Comment: Да, алгоритм изменен. Вы, как я понял, дали код, соответствующий требованиям ТЗ. Вдруг, если человеку нужно будет, он посмотрит мое решение. Часто вопросы пишут странно и плохо формулируя то самое ТЗ.

Comment: да, это понятно. Я потому и написал сразу "если алгоритм не менять", так как мне тоже хотелось переписать (но я себя заставил:-).

Comment: Просто, честно говоря, алгоритм - жесть). Я понял, что ошибка в условии, но, откровенно говоря, было лень дальше думать. Проще и быстрее написал свое решение...)

Comment: только я бы попроще сделал - всё в одну простую строчку помещается. Автор неплохо придумал с индексом [:4], так что переиспользовал его идею:-) Добавил в свой ответ.

Comment: а разве не надо перегнать срез в int?

Comment: Не вижу в условии ошибки. Про какую ошибку вы говорите?

Comment: @sayfdor, вы правы - надо пергнать в int:-)

Comment: @2000, полагаю, про "строка с удалением ломает алгоритм"  (так как она ничего не ломает -всё с ней работает, как видите, теперь верно)

Comment: Да, спасибо. Моя ошибка была в том, что не менялась переменная minn, т.к. была объявлена вне цикла while

Comment: @2000, переменная ведь может меняться, даже если объявлена не в цикле). У вас было условие какое-то кривое, поэтому после 1 итерации if заваливался всегда. Сергей все поправил)

Comment: Я все-таки еще раз ошибся в причине ошибки. Алгоритм перезаписи minn то был правильный, но она всегда была минимальным значением, которое после for удалялось из out. Поэтому следующего минимального, которое меньше чем minn просто не было...  А minn должно быть больше за следующую искому сумму

Comment: условие выхода всё равно было неверным, как понимаю:-)

Comment: @Сергей, да, конечно. Оно как-то криво работало. После того, как оно находило -300, дальнейшие данные были уже больше -300, потому minn не могло измениться, даже если бы его переопределение было адекватно написано)

Comment: Было верным.  Но minn не менялось, поэтому следующее число не находилось.
Поэтому после переопределения, когда minn объявлена после while то все стает на свои места.
И условие выхода работает правильно - потому что после очередного завершения for -  minn становится больше следующего минимального числа.
А ранее оно не менялось и это было ошибкой